# GHC package is hidden

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to run this simple example that I got from the [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/GHC/As_a_library).

```
import GHC
import GHC.Paths ( libdir )
import DynFlags

main = 
    defaultErrorHandler defaultFatalMessager defaultFlushOut $ do
      runGhc (Just libdir) $ do
        dflags <- getSessionDynFlags
        setSessionDynFlags dflags
        target <- guessTarget "test_main.hs" Nothing
        setTargets [target]
        load LoadAllTargets
```

The error messages I'm getting are:

```
amy@wombat$ ghc --make amy15.hs 

amy15.hs:1:8:
    Could not find module ‘GHC’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘ghc-7.8.3’.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

amy15.hs:3:8:
    Could not find module ‘DynFlags’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘ghc-7.8.3’.
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

Now, `ghc-7.8.3` is what I'm using to do the compilation, so obviously the package is installed.

```
amy@wombat$ cabal info ghc
* ghc              (library)
    Versions available: [ Not available from server ]
    Versions installed: 7.8.3
... and so on
```

Why can't GHC see the `ghc` package?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most packages are indeed hidden.

To unhide them temporarily, you may use `ghc --make amy15.hs -package ghc-7.8.3`.

To unhide permanently, use the method @mhwombat suggested.

Comment: why hidden, for what ?

Answer (score 12):

Apparently the `ghc` package is hidden by default, at least if you install ghc manually the way I did, rather than installing the Haskell platform. So I needed to "un-hide" the package as follows:

```
sudo ghc-pkg expose ghc
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use cabal to build your program and list the `ghc` package as a dependency.