# it is a hidden module in the package `time-1.5' when run " :load Data.Time.Clock.UTC"

Tags: haskell

I am trying `BetterPredicate.hs` of [Real World Haskell's chapter 9](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/io-case-study-a-library-for-searching-the-filesystem.html), the snippet code about `ClockTime` throws error under my `ghc 7.6.3`:

```
    Couldn't match expected type `ClockTime'
            with actual type `time-1.4.0.1:Data.Time.Clock.UTC.UTCTime'
```

According to Hyogeol Lee's comment to the online version of the book, `"getModificationTime does not returns ClockTime type in ghc 7.6.3, but you can use UTCTime instead."` , under prelude prompt, I tried: `+m Data.Time.Clock.UTC`, I got the following error:

```
<no location info>:
Could not find module `Data.Time.Clock.UTC'
It is a member of the hidden package `time-1.4.0.1'.
it is a hidden module in the package `time-1.5'
it is a hidden module in the package `time-1.4.0.1'
```

My result of `ghc-pkg list time` is

```
ghc-pkg list time
/usr/lib64/ghc-7.6.3/package.conf.d
time-1.4.0.1
/home/abelard/.ghc/x86_64-linux-7.6.3/package.conf.d
time-1.5
```

But I still have no idea what should I do?

*Edit*: According to user2407038, I use `ghc-pkg unregister time-1.5` to remove time-1.5, after that, I got the similar error:

```
:m +Data.Time.Clock.UTC
Could not find module `Data.Time.Clock.UTC'
It is a member of the hidden package `time-1.4.0.1'.
it is a hidden module in the package `time-1.4.0.1'
```

and

```
Prelude> :m +Data.Time.Clock
<no location info>:
Could not find module `Data.Time.Clock'
It is a member of the hidden package `time-1.4.0.1'.
```

*Edit 2*: after reading the aswers to [GHC package is hidden](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26145383/1054800), and changing `BetterPredicate.hs` 's code:
`System.Time(ClockTime(..))` into `Data.Time.Clock(UTCTime)`, the following two ways can work for me:

1. compile the file BetterPredicate.hs: `ghc --make BetterPredicate.hs -package time-1.4.0.1`
2. using `sudo ghc-pkg expose time-1.4.0.1` to unhide it, and then, under `ghci`, I can successfully load the module `Data.Time.Clock` :

`:m +Data.Time.Clock`

`*Main Data.Time.Clock> :t UTCTime`

```
 UTCTime
 :: time-1.4.0.1:Data.Time.Calendar.Days.Day -> DiffTime -> UTCTime
```

Comment: You have multiple versions of time, you will almost certainly have problems with this so you should unregister one. Data.Time.Clock.UTC doesn't seem to exist in *any* version of time. `getModificationTime` simply returns a `UTCTime` which is in `Data.Time.Clock`.

Comment: What exactly is the snippit of code about `ClockTime` that throws an error?

Comment: I ask because I don't see `Data.Time.Clock` anywhere in `BetterPredict.hs`

Comment: user5402, I am sorry! I made a stupid mistake that I forgot to use the origin code for reproducing the error of this stackoverflow question. It should be `System.Time` in the origin snippet, which will lead a error `Couldn't match expected type `ClockTime'` under ghc 7.6.3

Comment: You need to post your version of `BetterPredicate.hs` and show exactly what line the error is on.

Answer (score 2):

To fix the `BetterPredicate.hs` module in RWH Chapter 9 you have to do the following:

1. import Data.Time.Clock
2. Change the definition of Predicate to use UTCTime instead of ClockTime
3. import SomeException from Control.Exception
4. define a `handleAny` function
5. use `handleAny` instead of `handle` in the `saferFileSize` and `getFileSize` functions

:

```
import Data.Time.Clock (UTCTime)
import Control.Exception (bracket, handle, SomeException)
...
type Predicate =  FilePath      -- path to directory entry
               -> Permissions   -- permissions
               -> Maybe Integer -- file size (Nothing if not file)
               -> UTCTime       -- last modified
               -> Bool
...
handleAny :: (SomeException -> IO a) -> IO a -> IO a
handleAny = handle
...
saferFileSize path = handleAny (\_ -> ...
...
getFileSize path = handleAny (\_ -> ...
```

Fixed code is here: http://lpaste.net/116709

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to "load the the UTCTime type / constructor."

Comment: I can run `:m +Data.Time.Clock`, but I found `UTCTime` was not direct sub type of `Clock`, when running `:t getModificationTime`, I got `
getModificationTime` :: `FilePath -> IO time-1.4.0.1:Data.Time.Clock.UTC.UTCTime`

Comment: user5402, Thank you for your time! It seems that `... hidden package time-1.4.0.1` is my real question. And I have tried to replace all `ClockTime` with `UTCTime`.

Comment: Yeah - try 'ghc-pkg hide time-1.5` to see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: user5402, I am sorry, my above comment is not very clear. I have updated my question and appended two notes where I explained that `... hidden package time-1.4.0.1` was my real question. So, I can not accept your answer  ^_^.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67177/discussion-between-abelard20008-and-user5402).