# cabal repl gives error "cannot find module" but it is listed as dependency and cabal build works

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

I have a project with a a library in a few directories. The cabal file is produced with `hpack` and looks ok. The project builds with `cabal build` and the main can be run with `cabal run xx`.

Using **repl in vscode**, I get **occasionally**

```
Could not load module ‘GIS.Subdivisions’
    It is a member of the hidden package ‘CatCoreConcepts-0.2’.
    Perhaps you need to add ‘CatCoreConcepts’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file.
```

The package is, of courese, listed in the dependencies. The error is not always occuring and I assume it is a probem with some data cached in the vscode Haskell HLS plugin. Is there a simple way to clean the cache of the plugin? Restart HLS and `Developer: reload window` in vscode is not having any effect.

Comment: Are you using `stack`? (I think so because the `hpack` usage). If you have a `stack.yaml` file, vscode haskell extension will try to `stack` as the cradle.  I don't know a lot about this but essentialy, cache, artifacts, etc... are expected to be compiled with `stack build`. If you are building with `cabal` then you need to create a `hie.yaml`. WIth `cradle`, `cabal`

Comment: I use cabal, not stack (at least not intentionally; I fear, stack is installed on my computer) and I relay on cabal to automatically produce the `hie.yaml` file. There is no `hie.yaml` file in my project.

Comment: Well, It doesn't matter if stack is installed as long as you don't have a `stack.yaml` file in your directory. So since you are not using `stack` I assume `hls` is confused about the `CatCoreConcepts` package (which is a local package, since I can't find it on hackage). Probably you should add the library as a component within the `hie.yaml`. It is difficult to tell because without looking at the project.

Comment: Also, `hpack` seem to not integrate well enough with newer versions of `cabal`, and it looks like you are trying complex build here, so writing the `.cabal` file yourself, might help.

Comment: @Ismor: The .cabal file is at `https://github.com/andrewufrank/CategoryCoreConcepts/blob/master/CatCoreConcepts.cabal`. I cannot see anything missing; can you check and identify what is missing or should be changed? Thank you.

Comment: Well, I see `GIS.Subdivisions` isn't part of `CatCoreConcepts`. I guess you are working in a local branch for version `0.2`. Also, the `hs-source-dirs:` looks wrong. Tipically you put the library under `src` with `hs-source-dirs: src` and the executables under `app` folder. I looks like you are saying that the whole folder is for the library, but clearly you have more than a library. You have tests, and executable.

Comment: @ismor - thank you for the advice. I have changed the directory structure per your suggestions and do not currently see the error message. --  It is somewhat annoying when a tool tacitly assumes e.g. a directory layout without stating it. I have now an additional directory level.

Comment: Actually, cabal does not assume a directory layout. You can configure `hs-source-dirs` field to understand a flat folder hierarchy. I think, what's not understood about cabal is its component system. From cabal's point of view, a file which will be part of the executable (for example, files with a `main` function) will be packed differently as files in tests or files in libraries. This is very different from other langs like python in which everything is a python script. Once you understand cabal's components, you'll find out that additional layers are a good practise, but not a requirement.

Comment: @lsmor - thank you - very helpful clarification. could you point me to some documentations about these differences in packaging? My `test` includes programs with a `main` and I would expect it to be packaged the same as what is in `app`. Where can I find more information?  -- additional question: does what you explain apply to programs built with `stack` similarly or is `stack` doing it differently?

Comment: I left an answer to explain your questions

Answer (score 2):

This is not an answer to the main question, but to some OP comments.

I'd say cabal [documentation](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html) is good (but lengthy).

A brief summary as I understand (not official documentation)

- A Package is a set of *components*
- A component is a set of *modules* (haskell files)

  - Module-name and file-name  must be equal except for *entrypoints* (see below)
- Components can be classified in two groups:

  - *runnables*: tests, benchmarks and executables

    - *runnables* must have a unique *main* function called the *entrypoint*
    - In the cabal file, you can use keywords `executable`, `test-suite` and `benchmark` for defining *runnables*
    - Within each *runnable* section in the cabal file there **must** be a field `main-is` pointing to the file with the *entrypoint*
    - The file-name of the entrypoint can be whatever but the module name **must** be `Main`.
    - Notice that *runnable* components can have multiple modules (haskell files). For example you can have a test suit consisting in a file with auxiliar functions and other file with the main function. Both files conform a component (a test-suite in this case)
  - *non-runnables*: libraries

    - In the cabal file, you can use keywords `library` for defining non-runnable component
    - For libraries you must specify the modules which are exposed with the `exposed-modules` keyword.
- Runnable components can import non-runnable ones even if they are defined in the same package. But viceversa is not true.
- As a good practice, each component should be separated in a different folder. Some libraries expect naming convention. For example: tests to be in a folder with the same name and with `test_XXXX.hs` format (this is regular across programing languages, not only Haskell)
- When libraries are separated in folders the field hs-source-dirs *must* be specified to point to the folder with the haskell files

(the name *runnable* is not part of the official docs, but is the way I understand)

`stack` works pretty much the same as `cabal` since the former is just a different front-end for the later. So aside from different keywords and `yaml` format, all of the above can be applied to `stack` (notice that cabal updates more often than stack, therefore some features supported by cabal can be missing in stack.)

If you find this useful, I think I am opening an issue to the cabal docs to include it.

Comment: Your explanations are very useful for me. A question left open: can i have more than one library directory, listed as `hs-source-dirs` (comma separated?)

Comment: @user855443 Up to the [cabal docs](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.4/cabal-package.html#pkg-field-hs-source-dirs) it is a directory list, so It should accept many comma separated values

Answer (score 0):

I have had the problem where VSCode thinks modules are hidden. Many answers on SO, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26145383/ghc-package-is-hidden). Possible solution, which hopefully helps,

```
ghc-pkg expose CatCoreConcepts
```

Answer (score 0):

Many weeks later, I found that I had some lines in `.ghci` and cleaned it to contain only `:set xxx` entries, no `:m xxx` and no `:l xxx`

I have the impression that a line with `:m ModuleX` was causing the error, producing a misleading error message.